# Android Studio: can't startActivity after putExtra with custom Parcelable object

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, parcelable

I segued this tutorial to pass custom object by Intent.

I have 2 fragments(fragmentA, fragmentB) and they are in 2 activities(activityA, activityB)

If I use `mIntent.putExtra("event","event");` `startActivity(mIntent)` works fine and the app shows the right page.

But when I have `Parcelable object`, `startActivity(mIntent)` seems don't have any effort app restart with this error:

```
    03-23 11:49:28.675    1288-1434/system_process E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
03-23 11:49:28.675    1288-1302/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ view not successfully added to wm, removing view
03-23 11:49:28.675    2311-2311/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-23 11:49:28.675    1288-1434/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Exception in new application when starting activity com.example.user10.myapplication/.TabbedActivityEvent
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
        at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:750)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:967)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:385)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:5003)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:5063)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:394)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2071)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-23 11:49:28.675    1288-1434/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force removing ActivityRecord{b142fc90 u0 com.example.user10.myapplication/.TabbedActivityEvent t6}: app died, no saved state
```

code for my custom object which implements Parcelable:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class EventParcelable implements Parcelable {
private int eventId;
private String title;
private String abstract_;
private String description;
private Bitmap image;
private String referenceFirstName;
private String referenceLastName;
private String referenceEmail;
private String referencePhone;
private String referenceMobile;
private int vote;
private int companyId;

public int getEventId(){
    return eventId;
}
public void setEventId(int eventId){
    this.eventId = eventId;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAbstract_(){
    return abstract_;
}
public void setAbstract_(String abstract_){
    this.abstract_ = abstract_;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
}

public Bitmap getImage(){
    return image;
}
public void setImage(Bitmap image){
    this.image = image;
}

public String getReferenceFirstName(){
    return referenceFirstName;
}
public void setReferenceFirstName(String referenceFirstName){
    this.referenceFirstName = referenceFirstName;
}

public String getReferenceLastName(){
    return referenceLastName;
}
public void setReferenceLastName(String referenceLastName){
    this.referenceLastName = referenceLastName;
}

public String getReferenceEmail(){
    return referenceEmail;
}
public void setReferenceEmail(String referenceEmail){
    this.referenceEmail = referenceEmail;
}

public String getReferencePhone(){
    return referencePhone;
}
public void setReferencePhone(String referencePhone){
    this.referencePhone = referencePhone;
}

public String getReferenceMobile(){
    return referenceMobile;
}
public void setReferenceMobile(String referenceMobile){
    this.referenceMobile = referenceMobile;
}

public int getVote(){
    return vote;
}
public void setVote(int vote){
    this.vote = vote;
}

public int getCompanyId(){
    return companyId;
}
public void setCompanyId(int companyId){
    this.companyId = companyId;
}

public static final Creator<Event> CREATOR = new Creator<Event>() {
    @Override
    public Event createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        Event mEvent = new Event();
        mEvent.eventId = source.readInt();
        mEvent.title = source.readString();
        mEvent.abstract_ = source.readString();
        mEvent.description = source.readString();
        mEvent.image = source.readParcelable(null);
        mEvent.referenceFirstName = source.readString();
        mEvent.referenceLastName = source.readString();
        mEvent.referenceEmail = source.readString();
        mEvent.referencePhone = source.readString();
        mEvent.referenceMobile = source.readString();
        mEvent.vote = source.readInt();
        mEvent.companyId = source.readInt();
        return mEvent;
    }

    @Override
    public Event[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Event[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.eventId);
    dest.writeString(this.title);
    dest.writeString(this.abstract_);
    dest.writeString(this.description);
    dest.writeValue(this.image);
    dest.writeString(this.referenceFirstName);
    dest.writeString(this.referenceLastName);
    dest.writeString(this.referenceEmail);
    dest.writeString(this.referencePhone);
    dest.writeString(this.referenceMobile);
    dest.writeInt(this.vote);
    dest.writeInt(this.companyId);
}
}
```

code for fragmentA which is in activityA to pass the data:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Event event = adapter.getItem(position);

           EventParcelable mEventParcelable = new EventParcelable();
            mEventParcelable.setEventId(event.eventId);
            mEventParcelable.setTitle(event.title);
            mEventParcelable.setAbstract_(event.abstract_);
            mEventParcelable.setDescription(event.description);
            mEventParcelable.setImage(event.image);
            mEventParcelable.setReferenceFirstName(event.referenceFirstName);
            mEventParcelable.setReferenceLastName(event.referenceLastName);
            mEventParcelable.setReferenceEmail(event.referenceEmail);
            mEventParcelable.setReferencePhone(event.referencePhone);
            mEventParcelable.setReferenceMobile(event.referenceMobile);
            mEventParcelable.setVote(event.vote);
            mEventParcelable.setCompanyId(event.companyId);

            Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), TabbedActivityEvent.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("event", mEventParcelable);

            startActivity(mIntent);

        }
    });
```

code for fragmentB in activityB to get the passed data:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listeventdescription_fragment,container,false);
   EventParcelable event1 = (EventParcelable) getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("event");
Log.d("result",event1.getTitle());

return view;
}
```

Comment: Of course you get an error. Look in the logcat (don't filter it, you might miss something)

Comment: added the logcat error. I was filtering it with app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [TransactionTooLargeException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html), it says that transaction buffer has a max size of 1Mb. As EventParcelable contains a Bitmap field it should exceed that max size.

If this bitmap comes from a file, just put file path instead bitmap in intent and reload bitmap in 2nd Activity. Otherwise you can maybe try to use a static field (or Singleton pattern) to make this bitmap available in both activities.

See David [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371389/android-base-activity-bases-global-variables-cant-get-from-some-activites/11373779#11373779) for an example of static variables.

Comment: if the max size is 1 MB, how can I pass data?

Comment: can you please write me some code for the 2° solution which use a static field or singleton patter? because this bitmap doesn't come from a file.

Comment: For an example of how to use static variables see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11373779/769265